# Is there a way to change my webcam's output buffer

Tags: opencv, discord

I was curious since opencv has a way to grab frames from your webcam, is there a way to edit the frame and insert it back into the webcam's buffer? I would want to do image editing in real time to edit out a static background. I would want to be able to create a dummy device that discord or zoom would be able to select to show the output buffer to.

Comment: What you mean by insert it back into the webcam's buffer?

Comment: you canot edit webcan buffer but you can process the image andgenerate a new buffer to streamit trought a socket or http

Comment: The idea is that I would want to be able to edit the video stream and use it in either discord or zoom. So the buffer would have to be considered a device to be usable there.